# Is the req.user passed to the client?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, express-session

I'm using node.js, express, express-session and passport.js to handle authentication in my project. In my routes.js I handle get-requests like this:

```
app.get('...', isLoggedIn, function(req, res, next) {
    var user = req.user;
    ...
});
```

Inside the function I can get the user from the request parameter. My question is where the user object comes from? Is the user object passed to the client and back? Can the client change the user object in an attempt to inject code into my database?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Some basic info about where `req.user` comes from can be found on [Passport.js docs](http://passportjs.org/docs/login).

Comment: While your question is already answered, I suggest using a packet sniffer such as Wireshark to fully understand what goes between your browser and your application.

Answer (score 1):

`req.user` is intialized when session is created. `req.user` is equal to object user stored in session. Watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yvviEA1pOXw) video for more informations about authentication in node.js .And no, client cannot interact with you database through that.